# Python: Can I take a manifold object as a model

Tags: python, mds, manifold

I have a group of high-dimensional (250 dimensions) data. To get rid of unnecessary dimensions and to easily visualize data on a figure, I used class `sklearn.manifold.MDS` and its method `fit_transform(data)` and already got the transformed data in 2-dimension space.

I have plotted the figure out, which looks like 
[image]

**The problem is**: now I have some new coming data. In my case, I want to take the figure shown above as the basic model. For new coming data, I want to implement the same MDS on them and also plot them on this figure, so that I can know which area and how large area the new data will occupy.

However, I realized that `MDS` class only has `fit_transform()` method but doesn't have independent `transform()` method. **I want to know**, if for new coming data, I do another `fit_transform(new_data)`, can these transformed data be directly plotted on top of this figure?

p.s. I do `fit_transform(new_data)` after I do `fit_transform(old_data)`